# SQL Server : convert nvarchar year to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, nvarchar

I am trying to convert `nvarchar(5)` year of birth (e.g. 1972) to a `datetime` (e.g. 1972-06-01) in a SQL Server table.

Something like:

```
UPDATE TableName
SET DateOfBirth = CONVERT(datetime, YearOfBirth + '/01/01', 103)
```

This throws an error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

How can I solve this?

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Some non-ANSI SQL there...

Comment: Why does it become 1972-0**6**-01 ?

Comment: The best format if you really need to express dates as *string literals* is the adapted **ISO-8601** format in SQL Server : `YYYYMMDD` (no dashes, no spaces - nothing). This works for **all** regional/language settings - so try this: `CONVERT(datetime, YearOfBirth + '0101', 103)` and I'm pretty sure it'll work just fine

Comment: @marc_s correct me if I'm wrong bu ISO-8601 allows both 'yyyy-MM-dd' and 'yyyyMMdd'. But in the end, it's best no to store dates as strings.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: yes - but the style that SQL Server uses that works for all language / regional settings is **only** `yyyymmdd` - the one with the dashes *can fail* when trying to convert a varchar to datetime depending on settings

Answer (score 4):

What you are doing needs two steps:  store the value in the column as a date and then change the type.

In your case, a third step is needed, so the column is big enough to store the value string representation of the date value.  I think this will work in SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN DateOfBirth NVARCHAR(32);

UPDATE TableName
    SET DateOfBirth = YearOfBirth + '-01-01';

ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN DateOfBirth Date;
```

The first `ALTER TABLE` alters the column to be wide enough for the new month and day.  Then the date is constructed in a standard format (okay, leaving out the hyphens would be even more standard).  Then the column is transformed to a date.

If you just want something that looks like a date -- and a lot of criticism on Stack Overflow ;) -- you can eliminate the third step.

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need

```
UPDATE TableName
SET DateOfBirth = YearOfBirth + '-06-01'
Where YearOfBirth = '1972'
```